# NETWORKDAYS.INTL support missing in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, jexcelapi

I am using Apache POI 3.9 library & noticed that it complains me of below error for excel function

> Name 'NETWORKDAYS.INTL' is completely unknown in the current workbook

Is this formula supported in Apache POI ?.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Apache POI? What happens when you upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Gagravarr's comment . Issue fixed by upgrading POI library version to latest (3.17) which supports NETWORKDAYS.INTL